# UIButton shrinking image?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am working on an iPad UI and a button on that UI needs to have this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Q7f.jpg

(as a PNG). The button is being declared like this:

```
CGRect newNoteButtonRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 43);                         
UIButton* newNoteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:newNoteButtonRect];
newNoteButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[newNoteButton setImage:self.fNewNoteIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where 'fNewNoteIcon' is a UIImage. When the UI comes up, the image is tiny and squished, and almost nothing I do can change that. Any ideas?

The icon is initialized like this:

```
self.fNewNoteIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"New_Note.png"];
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to initialize self.fNewNotIcon?

Comment: post edited to include that

Comment: Thx.  Does your button have any title text?  What happens if you use the image as "setBackgroundImage:..." instead?

Comment: No, there's no title text. I think I've found the issue though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like if your PNG doesn't have an Alpha channel, then you'll have size issues. I opened the PNG in Photoshop and added an Alpha channel. The image is now properly sized in the iPad!

Answer (score 0):

In that provided code you haven't specified a `UIButton` type? Creating a button with a custom image

```
// Create image
self.fNewNoteIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttomImage.png"];

// Create rect for button. 0, 0 and size it from image
CGRect newNoteButtonRect = CGRectMake:(0, 0, _fNewNoteIcon.size.width, _fNewNoteIcon.size.height);

// Alloc and init UIButton with type
// Pass in image. Add to subview of view.
UIButton *newNoteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[newNoteButton setImage: _fNewNoteIcon forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview: newNoteButton];
```

I type all of this out in SO without compiling so check over but that should get you a UIButton, with the required image at the correct size.

Comment: Just tried that, it didn't work. I wonder if not having an alpha channel has an effect...